# R: non standard evaluation of arguments

Tags: r

I wish to pass an `expression` object to functions, so that its `substitute` gives identical results - and can't seem to get it right.

```r
f1 <- function(x) { 
  print(substitute(x))         # a + 1 
  print(class(substitute(x)))  # "call"
  f2(x)
}

f2 <- function(y) {
  print(substitute(y))         # x
  print(class(substitute(y)))  # "name"
}

f1(a+1)
```

What happens here?   Why the difference in classes, and in values of `substitute`?

Is there a way to achieve 'perfect forwarding' in R  (i.e, to pass the expression to functions as-is)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876164/functions-and-non-standard-evaluation-in-dplyr>

Comment: 1.the variable x is passed into the `f2` function due to lazy evaluation, hence having `f2` print `x` 2) No you cannot do a as-is forwarding due to the lazy evaluation of the promise.  Note that the variables will be evaluated ONLY WHEN NEEDED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the two function calls are

```
f1(a+1)
f2(x)
```

It doesn't matter what's actually in `a` or `x`, that's all the functions `f1` and `f2` see when they are called. In one case you are passing `a+1` which is call to the `+` function. In the other you are just passing `x` which just a symbol name. R treats these two types of situations differently thus they have different classes.

```
class(quote(a+1))
# [1] "call"
class(quote(a))
# [1] "name"
```

If you want "perfect" forwarding, then it's easiest not to catch the variable at all in the inter function and pass it through via the `...` mechanism.

```
f1 <- function(...) { 
  f2(...)
}

f2 <- function(y) {
  print(substitute(y))         # x
  print(class(substitute(y)))  # "name"
}

f1(a+1)
# a + 1
# [1] "call"
```

Otherwise `substitute()` will store the unevaulated expression in a variable, but if you want to expand that expression back into a function call, you need to use something like `do.call()`

```
f1 <- function(x) { 
  sx <- substitute(x)
  print(sx)
  print(class(sx))  # "call"
  
  do.call("f2", list(sx))
}

f2 <- function(y) {
  print(substitute(y))         # x
  print(class(substitute(y)))  # "name"
}

f1(a+1)
# a + 1
# [1] "call"
# a + 1
# [1] "call"
```